# Error:In JSON data submission unexpected character

Tags: json, onesignal

I am trying to send a push notification using onesignal.In that process i got an error

```
"error":"There was a problem in the JSON you submitted: unexpected character at line 1, column 1 [parse.c:652]"}
```

My Code is as follows:

```
var jsonBody = {
                  "app_id": "OneSignal App ID",
                  "include_player_ids": ["Onesignal Playerid"],
                  "headings": {
                      "en": "Sump"
                   },
                   "contents": {
                       "en": " Sump Level is 'Sumpper' "
                   }
               };
                var request = $.ajax({
                      url: "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications",
                      headers: {
                            'Authorization':'Basic REST API Key',
                            'Content-Type':'application/json',
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'SDK-Version',
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                        },
                      type: "POST",
                      data: jsonBody,
                      dataType: "json"
                });
                console.log(request);

                    request.success(function(msg) {
                      console.log("success");
                    });

                    request.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                      console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );

                    });
```

Can anyone help me where i am going wrong.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi try to create an object then stringfy it to json.

```
var jsonBody = 
          { 
           app_id: "OneSignal App ID",
           include_player_ids: [ "Onesignal Playerid", "Secondsignal Playerid"],
           headings : 
           {
              en: "Sump"
           },
           contents :{
             en: "Sump Level is 'Sumpper' "
           }  
         }; 

var request = $.ajax({
                      url: "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications",
                      headers: {
                            'Authorization':'Basic REST API Key',
                            'Content-Type':'application/json',
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'SDK-Version',
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                        },
                      type: "POST",
                      data: JSON.stringify(jsonBody),
                      dataType: "json"
                });
                console.log(request);

                    request.success(function(msg) {
                      console.log("success");
                    });

                    request.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                      console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );

                    });
```

Comment: Welcome! @Anusha